# Can I implement method that throws subtype of exception originally thrown in interface?

Tags: java, exception, polymorphism

There are two exceptions in my program:

```
class AnException extends Exception {};
class SpecialException extends AnException{};
```

I have an interface that defines method throwing `AnException`:

```
interface TheInterface {
    public void method() throws AnException;
}
```

There are more exceptions derived from `AnException` and more implementations of `TheInterface`. Which is why I want them to throw their original exceptions and have them casted to `AnException`:

```
public class Implementation1 implements TheInterface {
    //Error: Overriden method does not throw AnException
    public void method() throws SpecialException {
    }
}
```

At this moment, it might seem that the `AnExpception` derivatives are waste of time since they are never used and are imediatelly casted to their ancestor.
However, they are not thrown by `method()` directly and they have reason to exist. See this workaround I tried:

```
@Override
public void method() throws AnExpception {
    try {
        return new OtherClassThatThrowsExceptions();
    }
    catch(SpecialException e) {
        //Netbeans says that I can't cast SpecialException to AnException
        throw (AnExpception)e;   
    }
}
```

Comment: My Java is a bit hazy but I'm pretty sure you don't need that try-catch at all do you? Up-casting is done implicitly so there is no need to cast.

Comment: I thought so. But netbeans not mark the method implementation as: "Overriden method does not throw `AnException`"

Comment: Sorry but this question is unclear for me. Do you get some errors? If so where exactly and how your code looks like. For what I see you claim that in `Implementation1` you see "*Error: Overriden method does not throw AnException*" but I can't reproduce it. Also I don't see `implements TheInterface` in declaration of this class. Also what problem is your workaround suppose to solve? You are using there `return new ...` while return type of your method is `void` which is confusing. Did you mean `throw` by any chance?

Comment: What is the `method` is doing is completely irrelevant - except for the fact that this action can throw an exception which is child of `AnException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am not sure what is your problem. If you are asking if it is OK to override method with more specified exception then answer is **yes**.

Take a look. Lets say we have your exceptions and interface with your base method

```
class AnException extends Exception {};
class SpecialException extends AnException {};

interface TheInterface {
    public void method() throws AnException;
}
```

Now lets see if compiler will allow overriding method with more specified exception

```
class Implementation1 implements TheInterface {

    @Override  
    public void method() throws SpecialException {
        throw new SpecialException();
    }

}
```

As you see it compiled fine because there is no possible problem with this approach.

Lets say you use reference of type `TheInterface` and it holds instance of `Implementation1`

```
TheInterface interface1 = new Implementation1();
```

If you will want to use `method` from such reference compiler will require from you to handle `AnException` because it can't be sure that exactly kind of object `interface1` holds at moment of execution of this method. So you will need to write something like

```
try {
    interface1.method();
} catch (AnException e) {
    System.err.println("exception "+ e.getClass().getSimpleName()+ " handled");
}
```

and because `catch (AnException e)` will also catch actually thrown `SpecialException` since it is subtype of `AnException` exception is guaranteed to be handled.

In case you will use precise reference type to instance of `Implementation1`

```
Implementation1 implementation1 = new Implementation1();
```

compiler will require from you to handle `SpecialException` because this exception was specified in method signature. So if you would like to invoke `method` from this reference you will need to write

```
try {
    implementation1.method();
} catch (SpecialException e) {
    System.err.println("exception "+ e.getClass().getSimpleName()+ " handled");
}
```

and again your exception is guaranteed to be handled.

Comment: [I checked it out.](https://ideone.com/NahqOg) After thinking harder and debugging more carefully I discovered, that I used an exception name that already exists in Java and that I have imported incompatible imports for it (so that it couldn't be casted...).

Comment: So there was no problem with declaring method with more specified exception (as expected) but name conflict (who would guess?). That is why it is better to provide actual error massage to help us figure out your real problem faster. Also posting code which actually let us reproduce your problem would be very helpful. Anyway good job in debugging :)

Comment: I posted the actual error message. If I had posted all the code noone would even bother to read it - I can see a lot's of "*Fix this code*" questions with 0 activity around here. What I posted was incredibly simplified version of what I have - posted with assumption that I know what causes the trouble.

Comment: I agree that simplification of code is necessary but oversimplification can also be a problem. Just try to make sure that simplified code still reproduces your problem. That is all. Now since you discovered real cause of your problem I see that my answer doesn't actually contains solution. I don't mind if you unaccept my answer and post your own with explanation that "like Pshemo said in his answer, problem wasn't with declaring more specified exception in overridden method. My problem was ...." and accept your answer.